# Django db aggregation on timefield

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, aggregate

I have timefield in model.

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    total_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And here i create 2 records:

```
Model.objects.create(
    name='1',
    total_time=str(timedelta(seconds=0))
)
Model.objects.create(
    name='1',
    total_time=str(timedelta(seconds=100))
)
```

now when i do

```
records = Model.objects.filter(name='1')
for log in signal_logs:
    print(log.total_time)

signal_logs = signal_logs.aggregate(Sum('total_time'))
print('Total: ', signal_logs['total_time__sum'])
```

printed values are:

> 00:00:00
>
> 00:01:40
>
> Total: 140

This is not correct, total needs to be `100` or `00:01:40`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) instead, they support aggregation.

Comment: I tried, but still getting same result like for TimeField.

Comment: What version of Django do you use?

Comment: Django 1.10 version

Comment: It's strange! [I can't reproduce the problem.](https://wtf.jpg.wtf/f2/4c/1479806569-f24cc595bf792fe33211c54f0e4b1480.png)